# Find out the angles in a given triangle

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

> In a $\Delta ABC$, $a=7$, $c=9$ & $\angle A=36^\circ$. The values of $\angle B$ & $\angle C$ are
>
> a.) $94.91^\circ$ & $49.09^\circ$
>
> b.) $95.4^\circ$ & $48.6^\circ$
>
> c.) $13.09^\circ$ & $130.91^\circ$
>
> d.) both a & c

I have applied Sine Rule as follows
$$\frac{\sin A}{a}=\frac{\sin C}{c} $$$$\sin C=\frac{9}{7}\sin 36^\circ \implies C\approx 49.09^\circ$$ Thus I obtained $\angle B=94.91^\circ$ & $\angle C=49.09^\circ$ & found option (a) is correct, but my book gives option d.) as correct. Could any please explain?

I am 12th grade. Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Consider adjacent angles.

Comment: You can obtain the degree symbol by typing ^\circ in math mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This figure below explains everything.

[image]

Comment: Nice picture for illustration.

Answer (score 3):

Remember that
$\sin(a) = \sin(180-a)$.

$\sin C=\frac{9}{7}\sin 36^o \implies C\approx 49.09^o
$

Therefore if
$\sin(C) = \frac{9}{7}\sin 36^o$,
then $C$ can be either
$49.09^o$
or
$180^o-49.09^o
=130.91^o
$.

Answer (score 1):

If you draw a picture for the given data, you'll see you've got a "side-side-angle" situation, which in general does not have a unique solution.  That's why in this case there are *two* possibilities instead of just one.

(Minor TeX remark:  "^\circ" does a better job than "^o" of producing the degree symbol.)